# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)) after updating to Ruby 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-3

When I try to update our site to Ruby 3.0.0 I get this error:

**ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))**

```
 % rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.0)
irb(main):001:0> puts RUBY_VERSION
3.0.0
irb(main):002:0> puts IceCube::VERSION
0.16.3
irb(main):003:0> schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new
=> #<IceCube::Schedule:0x00007fccfe19cfa8 @start_time=2020-12-27 11:14:30 -0800, @all_recurrence_rules=[], @all_exception_rules=[]>
irb(main):004:0> puts schedule.to_ical
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4:in `<main>'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))
```

Here are the same commands with Ruby 2.7.2 which work

```
% rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.0)
irb(main):001:0> puts RUBY_VERSION
2.7.2
irb(main):002:0> puts IceCube::VERSION
0.16.3
irb(main):003:0> schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new
=> #<IceCube::Schedule:0x00007f9da3128fe8 @start_time=2020-12-27 11:12:50 -0800, @all_recurrence_rules=[], @all_exception_rules=[]>
irb(main):004:0> puts schedule.to_ical
DTSTART;TZID=PST:20201227T111250
```

What's confusing is that it also works with a plain ruby script with the *same gem versions* as the first example

```
% irb
irb(main):001:0> puts RUBY_VERSION
3.0.0
irb(main):002:0> gem 'ice_cube'
irb(main):003:0> require 'ice_cube'
irb(main):004:0> puts IceCube::VERSION
0.16.3
irb(main):005:0> schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new
=> #<IceCube::Schedule:0x00007ff2fb0d5b88 @start_time=2020-12-27 11:11:02 -0800, @all_recurrence_rules=[], @all_exception_rules=[]>
irb(main):006:0> puts schedule.to_ical
DTSTART;TZID=PST:20201227T111102
```

Does anyone know where I can start to fix this? We're just starting the project and I am hoping to use Ruby 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: `ice_cube` 0.16.4 [has already sorted out](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube/commit/66f1d797092734563bfabd2132c024c7d087f683) these compatibility problems with ruby 3.x, so just upgrade.

---

The issue has to do with [how keyword arguments are handled in ruby 3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/) and how `ice_cube` is [passing its arguments](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube/blob/v0.16.3/lib/ice_cube/i18n.rb#L13) to [`I18n.localize`](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/v1.8.5/lib/i18n.rb#L295).
So, extracting and simplifying the buggy code, this worked on ruby < 3

```
RUBY_VERSION # "2.7.2"

def foo(*args)
  bar(*args)
end

def bar(object, locale: nil, format: nil, **options)
  puts "object:#{object}"
  puts "locale:#{locale}"
  puts "format:#{format}"
  puts "options:#{options}"
end

foo('date', format: 'whatever')
# object:date
# locale:
# format:whatever
# options:{}
```

And from ruby >= 3

```
RUBY_VERSION # "3.0.0"

def foo(*args)
  bar(*args)
end

def bar(object, locale: nil, format: nil, **options)
  puts "object:#{object}"
  puts "locale:#{locale}"
  puts "format:#{format}"
  puts "options:#{options}"
end

foo('date', format: 'whatever')
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#        16: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
#        15: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
#        14: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
#        13: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
#        12: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
#        11: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
#        10: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:497:in `exec'
#         9: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
#         8: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
#         7: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
#         6: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `<top (required)>'
#         5: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `load'
#         4: from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.3.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
#         3: from (irb):11:in `<main>'
#         2: from (irb):3:in `foo'
#         1: from (irb):5:in `bar'
# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))
```

So, the fix I can see is to explicitely passing the parameters to the method:

```
def foo2(object, **options)
  bar(object, **options)
end

foo2('date', format: 'whatever')
# object:date
# locale:
# format:whatever
# options:{}
```

Or in terms of [the involved module](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube/blob/master/lib/ice_cube/i18n.rb):

```
module IceCube
  module I18n
    def self.l(object, **options)
      backend.l(object, **options)
    end
  end
end
```

and send a PR, use your own fork, monkey-patch, whatever works best for you.
But most important, brace yourself to find this issue in a lot of other gems, as the first stable ruby 3 version was just released [2 days ago](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/12/25/ruby-3-0-0-released/), so probably you'll have these type of issues with other gems, specially the unmaintained ones.
Good luck.

Comment: I forked the project to https://github.com/sthapit/ice_cube -- could you let me know what I should put in ice_cube/lib/ice_cube/i18n.rb to get this to work? This is a fairly popular gem so I assume it will be useful for many people

Comment: Check the changes I put in `self.l` method and apply them in your fork

Comment: I removed the delegated localize method and added your code and it works great https://github.com/sthapit/ice_cube/blob/master/lib/ice_cube/i18n.rb -- before I send a PR does something similar also need to be done for the translate method that was being delegated together with localize?

Comment: that works!! thank you so much -- I have accepted the answer and we'll also be using the master branch

Comment: I wish I understood any of this. So confusing.