# ruby 3 array argument splat with keyword arguments

Tags: ruby, ruby-3

Before ruby 3 it was possible to do sth like this

```
def test a, **o
  p a, o
end
t = [:ok, **{ok: 2}]
test *t
```

it would properly assign

:ok to a
and {ok: 2} to o

invoking in ruby 3

you will get

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))
```

Is there work around to splat array argument that holds keyword argument on second position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArgumentError after updating from Ruby 2.7 to Ruby 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65471481/895789)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send the second parameter as a hash you need to do next:

```rb
def test a, o
  p a, o
end
t = [:ok, {ok: 2}]
test *t
```

because of the separating keyword and positional arguments.