# ArgumentError when upgrading from Ruby 2.7 to 3.0 - related to separation of positional and keyword arguments?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.7, ruby-3

I am trying to upgrade gems from ruby 2.7.0 to 3.0.0. I have tried to read and plan ahead for what roadblocks I'd hit, like the [Separation of positional and keyword arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/).

I have updated two gems smoothly, but I have started to upgrade a third and, while testing the 3.0 update with RSpec, have run into the following error:

```
ArgumentError:
        wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keyword: children)
```

I am trying it instantiate a Class through a Factory. The stack trace is pointing back to the arguments of this function:

```
      # rubocop:disable Style/KeywordParametersOrder
      def initialize(parent_obj: nil, children:, **attributes)
        @attributes = attributes
        @parent = parent_obj
        @children_json = children
      end
      # rubocop:enable Style/KeywordParametersOrder
```

Though I don't *think* it is significant, I have included the rubocop dis/enable lines just in case they are important.

The Factory is calling the class in this fashion:

```
data = {:some_data=>"foo", :some_name=>"bar", :children=>[]}
Long::Class::Name.new(data)
```

Now, when I pry into the code between data and Long::Class::Name.new(data) and instantiate my own Long::Class::Name like below:

```
Long::Class::Name.new(children: children, attributes: data)
```

it results in a successful creation without the ArgumentError.

I think to myself, "Cool, I'll just update the Factory's Class call to this new format and re-run the tests." After doing this, I am still getting the same ArgumentError as above.

I *believe* this is an issue with positional/keyword arguments like I linked above, but I am having trouble seeing how I can correct this. Besides the link above, I have also looked into [Ruby 3 Keyword Arguments](https://juanitofatas.com/ruby-3-keyword-arguments), as well as [Hash and Keyword Coercion and Ruby 3 Changes](https://medium.com/building-rigup/hash-and-keyword-coercion-213425f69719). I believe I am facing the "Unforeseen Consequences" portion of that last link.

I have also looked at this Stack Overflow issue about [ArgumentError after updating from Ruby 2.7 to Ruby 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469682/argumenterror-after-updating-from-ruby-2-7-to-ruby-3-0) and tried to understand how I could use the first portion of the first answer to help me with my issue (disregarding the Update related to a PR).

Any thoughts on how can I dispel or work around this error? I have many gems I need to update and I am sure this will not be the last time I see this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this…

```
data = {:some_data=>"foo", :some_name=>"bar", :children=>[]}
Long::Class::Name.new(data)
```

…you are calling the method with one positional argument (a hash containing the keys `:some_data`, `:some_name`, and `:children`) and no keyword argument.

If you instead were to call it like this…

```
Long::Class::Name.new(**data)
```

…you would be calling it with no positional argument and three keyword arguments.

This is called the "double splat" and was introduced for exactly your usecase, turning a hash into keyword arguments.

Comment: Good news, the update DOES work! :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to save face a little:

I tried this early on, but I didn't magnify down to one set of tests so I didn't see that it worked. I just saw "46 tests failed" and thought the ** added didn't work (amateur move on my part, lesson learned!).